# Create arrows in plot with geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

I have a code using geopandas which plots the electrical system of my city. I have data of the average vectorial velocity of the wind, and I wish to plot this information as arrows in the same plot. I searched the documentation of geopandas and did not found anything related. Is there a way to make theses arrows in the plot using geopandas or any other python library? I know how to do something similar with OpenCV, but in my case, I have the geographic coordinates and not the position of the pixel in the images.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand. Can you give exemplar data so we can try them?

Comment: geopandas produces matplotlib axes. so you are basically looking for how to plot arrow on axes: https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html#annotating-with-arrow